# How to call devise sign_in and sign_out methods of devise from another controller different from devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I have a Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 application and my user authentication with `devise`but and I have an alternative `sign up` and `sign in` methods, I allow my users to sign up using their `Facebook` account then I save that login info in my `users` table the same one that devise uses to register and login users.

Steps

1. ✔ User click on the Facebook button.
2. ✔ I save his info (name and email extracted from `Koala`) I give the user a generic password.
3. ☐ Login this new user with devise.
4. ✔ Redirect to my main controller.

I'm just missing the 3rd step because I want to keep using the `current_user` helper and the `user_signed_in?` helper too.

So how do I tell devise to sign in this user automatically from my other controller?

I saw something like that on this question [Devise: Have multiple controllers handle user sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6143814) and it logs my user in but leads me to an blank page...

Answer (score 22):

Devise offers a [bunch of helpers](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers), two of which are these:

```
sign_in(resource_or_scope, *args)
sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, *args)
```

You can use these from any controller.

**EDIT**

If using `sign_in` already works for you but leaves the user on a blank page, check your logfile to see if there is a redirect going on, and where it redirects to. Or just make the redirect explicit by using the second of the helpers above.

Comment: I tried this, but then when I redirect from the controller to another page the user is no longer signed in.  There is nothing in the user session.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Include Devise helpers in your controller and all the normal devise methods, e.g. `sign_in` or `sign_out` would automatically be available there.

```
class TestController < RocketPants::Base
  include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
```

Fortunately, if your controller extends `ApplicationController`, Devise includes these helpers as convenience methods automatically.

But, the `RockePants` repo explains a specific case where the controller doesn't extend `ApplicationController`, and thus this explicit `include  Devise::Controllers::Helpers` is required 
https://github.com/filtersquad/rocket_pants/issues/7

Also, the official Devise docs are helpful to find other methods you will be able to use by including helpers
http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers