# Rails automatic sign in of user without sign in page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller method that is called as a return url like this

```
....../paypal/success
```

That looks like this ,

```
 def success   
            transaction = Transaction.find_by_token(params[:token])
            transaction.payer_id = params[:payer_id] 
            transaction.save
            @current_user = user = User.find(transaction.user_id)   
            username = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            password = "7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            signature = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"       
            version = 98
            @amount = Currency.convert(user.currency, "USD", transaction.amount.to_f).to_f.round(2)
            url = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp?USER=#{username}&PWD=#{password}&SIGNATURE=#{signature}&VERSION=#{version}&METHOD=DoExpressCheckoutPayment&TOKEN=#{transaction.token}&PAYERID=#{transaction.payer_id}&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=#{@amount}&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD"       
            uri = URI.parse(url)
            http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
            http.use_ssl = true
            http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE 
            request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
            res = http.request(request)
            response = res.body
            transaction.save
            user.balance = (user.balance+transaction.amount)
            user.save()         
            transaction.status ="Completed"
            transaction.save()  
            flash[:notice] = 'Payment Transaction Completed. Thank you for using skyline SMS'
            redirect_to user_home_path(@current_user)
```

However, the lines

```
redirect_to user_home_path(@current_user)
```

instead takes the user to sign in page.

How can i sign in the user from the method so that they are redirected to the their home page.

Authentication system is devise
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which authentification process do you use ? Devise ?

Comment: @Baldrick, yes devise

Comment: Devise has a `sign_in()` method you can use.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828500/how-to-call-devise-sign-in-and-sign-out-methods-of-devise-from-another-controlle

Comment: @Chandranshu so should i just call sign_in(user). Please help me here while i look through the documentation

Comment: Yes, where user is the instance of the User you want to be signed in. Should I capture this in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `sign_in()` method from [`Devise::Controllers::Helpers`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb) which are already mixed into the ApplicationController and hence available to all your controllers. So, in your success action, you'll do the following:

```
user = User.find(transaction.user_id) 
sign_in(user)
```

The Devise::Controllers::Helpers in turn include [`Devise::Controllers::SignInOut`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/sign_in_out.rb) which is where you'll see the real code.