# How to programmatically sign in a user through Devise in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, testunit

I need to have a custom mechanism for signing in using Devise with Rails 4. So I found the `sign_in` method in [Devise's test helpers section of their documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers):

```
sign_in @user          # sign_in(resource)
```

But is that the proper way to sign someone in from the web? In particular, will it do all the things Devise does when a user signs in, like recording the date/time stamps, IP addresses, sign in counts, etc? Or is this just for testing purposes?

Comment: sign_in doesn't authenticate a user it just signs the user in. Have a look at this issue https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1230

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the proper and standard way to programatically sign a user in.  Looking at the devise login code [sessions#create](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb) you can see they use this method as well.

Comment: looks like `sign_in` doesn't update all the other fields for the `User` model I referenced above, so I'll have to do that manually or figure out some easy devise method to call. Otherwise you're right, devise uses `sign_in` internally.

Answer (score 13):

Devise offers a bunch of helpers, two of which are these:

```
sign_in(resource_or_scope, *args)
sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, *args)
```

You can use these from any controller.

If using `sign_in` already works for you but leaves the user on a blank page, check your logfile to see if there is a redirect going on, and where it redirects to. Or just make the redirect explicit by using the second of the helpers above.

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8123646/2034097

Answer (score 4):

Long story short: Yes, sign_in @user does all the things that devise would normally do when a user signs in. It could be useful, for example, allowing an Administrator to sign in as one of their users.

[How To: Sign in as another user if you are an admin](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Sign-in-as-another-user-if-you-are-an-admin)